# How to run all django tests, even if some failed

Tags: django

How is it possible to show execution of each test, even if some tests failed. Now `python manage.py test` executes until the first fail.

Comment: It should run all tests and show the results, unless you're using the [`--failfast`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-test-failfast) option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.10/ref/django-admin/#test), the behaviour you are looking for is the default one. Running `python manage.py test` **should** run all the tests regardless of their results.

Using the `--failfast` flag on the other hand would stop as soon as a failure is encountered.

Comment: How to continue tests if fixture failed? Deserialization Error: Post has no field named 'content'. Ran 0 tests in 0.108s

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what aumo said, please remember that each method is 1 test. So, if you have multiple `assert` statements in 1 test method, then the remaining asserts will not be checked, if the first `assert` fails, independent of your `failfast` setting.

To have all assert statements run, you would need to split your test method into multiple test methods.